# check map keys are in set using std::equal or std::all_of

Tags: c++, predicate

I'm new to C++ and predicates but I'm running into a problem. I'm trying to check if all keys in an `unordered_map` exist in a `set` or even keys in another map with different value type for that matter.
Essentially, `[key in set_ for key in map_.keys()]` OR `[key in map2_ for key in map1_.keys()]` in python.

one approach is the following:

```
for( auto itr = map_.begin(); itr != map_.end(); ++itr ) {
    if( set_.find( itr->first ) == set_.end() ) return false;
}
```

But I want to use `std::all_of` or `std::equal` to achieve the same. Here's what I have so far:

```
some_function() {
    //set_ and map_ in scope
    areEqual = std::equal( map_.begin(), map_.end(), set_, 
        []( auto itr ){ return set_.find( itr->first ) != set_.end(); } );
}
```

compiler complains that `set_` is out of scope in `return set_.find(...)...`

I also tried

```
class checker {  
public:  
    bool operator()( map_itr itr )  
    { return set_.find( itr->first ) != set_.end(); }
};
```

but ran into the same problem.

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You have to capture set: `[&set_](..){..}`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference is good candidate too.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not really used to the sorted range algorithms, would it actually work in the case of `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: set operations require sorted ranges, so incompatible with `unordered_*`.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas can't access variables declared in its scope by default. In order to access your `set_` variable from the lambda function, you should *capture* it in the lambda function.

The capture list is defined between the `[]` characters at the beginning of the lambda function.

In this case, I would use `[&]` which captures all objects from the scope by reference, including your `set_` variable.

```
some_function() {
    areEqual = std::equal( map_.begin(), map_.end(), set_, 
        [&]( auto itr ){ return set_.find( itr->first ) != set_.end(); } );
}
```

You should read the [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) page on cppreference for further information.